# Jquery - Background colour animation

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a li item change background colour when you over over it, this is the code I am trying to get working; for some reason it isn't.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.navbar ul li').mouseover(function() {
      $(parent).animate({'backgroundColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)'}, 200);
   });
});
```

Comment: You'll need jQuery UI for that: http://jqueryui.com/animate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to animate the parent element, may be you should do this :

```
$(this).animate({'backgroundColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)'}, 200);
```

Comment: No, I forgot to take that out, I am trying to animate the list item of the list.

Comment: @AlexRickells I have edited my answer, so you just take out the parent() selector.

Comment: I have tried this and it still doesn't change the colour, the colour just doesn't react when you hover over it.

Comment: @AlexRickells have you import the js of jquery-ui animate ?

Comment: That might help.. it works now :/ Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @AlexRickells That's all right, could you accept my answer ?